# Nginx reverse proxy gets blocked

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, ip-blocking

We run a wordpress blog in a subdirectory from our main domain.

```
domain.com => Server A (Nginx)
domain.com/blog => Server B (Apache)
```

The blog itself lies on a different (cheap shared hosting) server and gets reverse proxied.

```
Nginx => Apache
```

As every request to the blog gets tunneld trough our main server, **Server B** continuously blocks our **Server A IP** address, as all requests come from the same IP. If a lot of requests hit at the same time (mostly crawlers) we get blacklisted for 10 minutes and it results in a 502 bad gateway error.

Is there any way to pass the real IP address to Server B? Or knows somebody another solution, without upgrading to a root server?
Hosting the wordpress blog on Server A is sadly not an option right now.

Answer (score 1):

If the "cheap shared hosting" supports it, you could forward the original requester IP:
`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`
So hopefully your reverse proxy's IP wont gets blocked.

If you want to block a list of bots you can check this question/answer out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24820722/940009

Answer (score 0):

5 years late.

No. But you can block the crawlers?

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* bot)
{
    return 404;
}
```

Untested.